# HTML selected is not working with Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, select, drop-down-menu

I'm working with  and  in angular,

In my template there is enumeration hardcoded as possible value:

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
  <select id="content_type_select" name="content_type"  class="form-control multiselect-select-one" [(ngModel)]="selectedContent.contentType" data-fouc>
    <option [selected]="selectedContent.contentType===ContentType.Image" [value]="ContentType.Image">Image</option>
    <option [selected]="selectedContent.contentType===ContentType.Video" [value]="ContentType.Video">Video</option>
    <option [selected]="selectedContent.contentType===ContentType.Text"  [value]="ContentType.Text">Txt</option>
    <option [selected]="selectedContent.contentType===ContentType.HTML"  [value]="ContentType.HTML">HTML</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

In my typescript I'm sending selectedContent to a template and I've loged in in cosole to check value of my selectedContent and it looks like this:

[image]
As you can see when I `console.log(this.selectedContent)` there is property `contentType` which has value of 1 and in my dropdown there should be Image selected, but nothing is selected acctually..

[image]

But if I write `[selected]="true"` then that option is selected... how come :/

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: Where are you getting `ContentType.Image` `ContentType.Video` etc... ? Surly if content type 1 === Image your code should read `[selected]="selectedContent.contentType===1"`

Comment: At the console log you are getting number try to replace `ContentType.Image` with `1` at the `HTML` and I think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to provide a bit more of context (like the implementation of **ContentType** enumeration). But let me provide you some usual answer for this kind of problem.

Enumerations are not made automatically available on the template simply because they are imported on component's class. Assuming you have an enumeration like

```
export enum ContentType {
  Image = 1,
  Video = 2,
  Text = 3,
  HTML = 4
}
```

If you need to consume it from template, it must first be associated to some publicly available class property, e.g. `public readonly contentType = ContentType` and then referenced like this on template code:

```
<select id="content_type_select" name="content_type"  class="form-control multiselect-select-one" [(ngModel)]="selectedContent.contentType" data-fouc>
    <option [selected]="selectedContent.contentType === contentType.Image" [value]="contentType.Image">Image</option>
    <option [selected]="selectedContent.contentType === contentType.Video" [value]="contentType.Video">Video</option>
    <option [selected]="selectedContent.contentType === contentType.Text"  [value]="contentType.Text">Txt</option>
    <option [selected]="selectedContent.contentType === contentType.HTML"  [value]="contentType.HTML">HTML</option>
  </select>
```

Also, be careful on JavaScript types, as the identity operator is being utilised. `1 == "1"` but `1 !== '1'`.